# Highcharts Legend error: "typeError: a.legendItem.bBox is undefined"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

`Fiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/6B7cr/

In Firefox (but not in Chrome):

I am getting errors, and the chart does not render, when the legend height exceeds the chart height.

In the example above, all that renders are the legend item elements, all in the same space.  No chart, no legend box, etc. I get the following error:

```
"Error: TypeError: a.legendItem.bBox is undefined
Source File: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js
Line: 183"
```

If I remove the `layout: 'vertical'` from the options, I get no error.
If I set the height of the container element larger, I get no error.

Examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/6B7cr/6/  (commented out layout: 'vertical')
- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/6B7cr/7/  (made container element taller)

This appears to be a new problem with the latest release.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

thanks,

Jamie

{{edit: screenshot:

[image: screen shot of problem on fiddle]

Comment: I run this all examples in FF26 on MacOSX and Windows7 and all works properly, charts are printed. Which version of FF do you have?

Comment: Well its strange, because I run your all examples in FF26 on W7, and I didn't receive any error. Have you tried to update jquuery / Highcharts?

Comment: The latest Highcharts is what caused the error :)  
I have updated the fiddle to use the latest jQuery, and the problem persists:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/6B7cr/

Comment: See my screenshot i42.tinypic.com/2druavt.jpg W7 SP1.

Comment: Ok, I see that it works for you.  It still doesn't work for me, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's a bug in 3.0.8 and 3.0.9 version. Working fine in 3.0.7 and upcoming version: http://jsfiddle.net/6B7cr/17/

Solution for now is to download master or still use 3.0.7:

- `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/3.0.7/highcharts.js"></script>`
- `<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js"></script>`

Thanks!